# Prediction variance in R

Tags: r, regression

Is there a way to get the variance of prediction for a linear regression model in R? The variance that I need is $s_f^2=s^2\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(x_{n+1}-\bar{x})^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2}\right)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `predict`. Have a look at `?predict` for any details. Also works for GLMs and any other models that have implemented the predict function. Example:

```
x <- rnorm(15)
y <- x + rnorm(15,sd=0.1)
mod = lm(y ~ x)
predict(mod,newdata=data.frame(x=0.5),type="response",interval="prediction",level=0.95) 
predict(mod,newdata=data.frame(x=0.5),type="response",interval="confidence",level=0.95)
```